# Why does a CSS transform,translate change the rotation for rotated elements?

Tags: html, css, d3.js

I have a number of elements that are rotated, and I wanted to translate them in order to shift their horizontal position.  However, when I performed a simple transform/translate, the rotation of the elements was lost and set back to what it was originally (with no rotation).

I fixed this by performing a transform/translate/rotate in order to shift the elements, but I am curious as to why the rotation is lost when I translate (x,y)?  I am using d3.js, so is it something with how that library handles the transformations, or does CSS do this naturally?

Comment: It's possible that the translate rule overrides the transform rule rather than appending

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as with every css-attribute.

Due to the cascading nature, if you re-define the transform declaration, only the latest changes will be applied:

```
.element{
   transform:rotate(angle);
   transform:translate3d(x,y,z);     /* now only the translation will be applied*/
}
```

In order to have both transformations applied, they need to be in one declaration:

```
.element{
   transform:rotate(angle) translate3d(x,y,z);
}
```

Since D3 uses CSS for it's transformations, previous ones will be overwritten by the newest one.

[small Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SYKLE/)